# PHP copying the result from a SQL Query into a CSV file writes only the last line

Tags: php, sql, oracle, csv

I'm trying to take some results from a query that I do to Oracle and paste them on a CSV file, the problem is that, in the foreach loop, the code should writes line by line, but he writes only the last line and I'm not able to understand the reason.

In the code I write an header of the csv file as you can see below, and this part is written in the csv file but then when I start the foreach loop he "sees" every line (because I tried to do a var_dump at every loop) but he writes only the last one.

The $res->rows is the variable that contains the rows outputted by the query.

```
$handle = fopen(Configuration::EXPORT_UPLOAD_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . explode('.', self::UPDATE_STATO_LIBRO_QUESTURA_TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME)[0] . '_BU_' . date("dmY") . '.csv', "w");
fwrite($handle, self::LIBRO_QUESTURA_UPDATE_COLUMN_NAME_NUMERO_PROTOCOLLO . ';');
fwrite($handle, self::LIBRO_QUESTURA_UPDATE_COLUMN_NAME_TRANCHE_MASSIVA . '_OLD;');
fwrite($handle, self::LIBRO_QUESTURA_UPDATE_COLUMN_NAME_TIPO_MANDATO . '_OLD;');
fwrite($handle, self::LIBRO_QUESTURA_UPDATE_COLUMN_NAME_COND_ECONOMICHE . '_OLD;');
fwrite($handle, self::LIBRO_QUESTURA_UPDATE_COLUMN_NAME_NUMERO_CONTRATTO . '_OLD' . PHP_EOL);
foreach($res->rows as $libroQuestura) {
    fputcsv($handle, $libroQuestura, ";");
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I suspect PHP is writing the file with CR newlines, but you're viewing the file on a system that uses LF, so all the lines are writing over each other.

Comment: Do you see all the lines if you look at a hex dump of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fopen - to append contents to a file use the 'a' parameter not 'w'

Comment: You are correct, it was so stupid, it's probably that I was tired

Comment: As long as you cracked it :)